# Cannot get image data from GStreamer while launching with .desktop file (written in pyqt5 and opencv)

Tags: opencv, pyqt5, ubuntu-20.04, gstreamer-1.0

I tried to build desktop application with PyQt5+opencv for image recognition system. I’m using GStreamer pipline to get rtsp streaming by

```
rtsp_url = “rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.50/live1.sdp latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink”
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`
```

I can run the .py script properly from terminal with python3 ./myapp.py , but after creating myapp.desktop and launching it, i get no image frame from gstreamer.

I’ve already tested with `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url,cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`, it works properly from both terminal and .desktop.
Is there any necessary to adjust gstreamer setting to launch from .desktop?
Also, the following is my app.desktop file.

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Version=1.0
Comment=MyApp_version1
Exec=python3 /home/waing/Codes/pythonQtTest_GUI/qtpythontest.py
Icon=/home/waing/HumanDetectionSystem/Myapp_Logo.png
Path=/home/waing/Codes/pythonQtTest_GUI/
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

[the result of cv2.getBuildInformation()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHrcG.png)

Is there anything that I need to change?
Thanks in Advance,
Waing

Comment: I'd start by removing that first line, as that's not part of the desktop entry syntax and makes it ambiguous (especially if that file is made executable).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your comment. I deleted the first line. But it gives the same reult.

Comment: Are you using a venv? Do you see the terminal window when you open the desktop file?

Comment: @musicamante I'm not using virtual environment. The terminal is shown but there is no error messages there. I can open my app GUI and can click the buttons or access all the files and the other options. But still can't get the image data from gstreamer.

Comment: Then I suggest to take your time and provide a proper [mre].

Comment: I cannot launch gstreamer with python script.
But after creating executable file with pyinstaller, I finally get the image data from gstreamer while launching with .desktop .